# launch a particular activity of an app which is not running to the foreground by shaking the phone

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm making an app where when i shake the device an activity is launched on the foreground. I've used a service and a BroadcastReciever. I don't know what im doing wrong

## **ShakeService.java**

this is my service class in that implements sensor events.

---

`

```
 public class ShakeService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private float acceleration;
    private float accelerationCurrent;
    private float accelerationLast;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        acceleration = 10f;
        accelerationCurrent = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
        accelerationLast = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
    
        accelerationLast = accelerationCurrent;
        accelerationCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x * x + y * y + z * z));
        float delta = accelerationCurrent - accelerationLast;
        acceleration = acceleration * 0.9f + delta;
    
        if (acceleration > 15) { // You can adjust the shake threshold as per your requirement
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, getCor_sendSms.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // Not used in this example
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
    
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

`

---

- 

> **ShakeReceiver.java**

this is my BroadcastReciever class

```
\`
```

```
public class ShakeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("ACTION_SHAKE")) {
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, getCor_sendSms.class);
            activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(activityIntent);
        }
     }

     }
```

```
\`
```

---

## Manifest file

`

```
<activity android:name=".getCor_sendSms" />         
    <service android:name=".ShakeService" />         
    <receiver android:name=".ShakeReceiver"             
     android:exported="true">         
     <intent-filter>          
       <action android:name="com.example.shake" />            
       </intent-filter>     
    </receiver>`
```

**get_cor_send_sms.java**
And this is the activity i want to launch when the device is shaken
`

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShakeService.class);     
    startService(intent);`
```